# How to add a certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities in UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate

I'm trying to add support for importing client certificates from a USB drive in a UWP application. I'm trying to search a `StorageFolder` (root of the USB drive) for files which match a regular expression `^.+[.]cer$`. So any file with extension `.cer`.

However the `.cer` file isn't included in the "files" list when I try to get all files from the `StorageFolder` like so:

```
List<StorageFile> files = (await folder?.GetFilesAsync()).ToList();
```

In the `Package.appxmanifest` file there's a list of supported file types in `Declarations`. If I try to include `.cer` here the solution won't build anymore because it is a prohibited file type and produces error

> .cer file type is reserved for system use.

Is it possible to manage the certificates like this?

How can I add support for importing `.cer` files to Trusted Root Certification Authorities in UWP?

Comment: Try following :            string[] results = Directory.GetFiles("path", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "^.+[.]cer$")).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng UWP has restricted file system access, I don't think that `Directory.GetFiles` will work

Comment: It will work if it authorization is allowed.

Comment: Hi, UWP is restricted by its own application container and cannot access certificate resources outside its own storage, but it can be changed by setting the capability of `sharedUserCertificates`. For details, please refer to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/certificates)